# Javascript/Jquery - Can't get date picker + selection verification to work

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have some code, which I believe is correct, however I can't seem to get it to work.

The use will input the date in the input field with the name "date" and how many people are going in the field named "people", and depending on these 2 variables they will get a specific cost, hence all the if statements.

Is there something I am missing here?

```
<p><input type="text" id="datepicker" name="date" value="Choose when you want to go"></p>
<select name="people" value="Are you sharing or single supplement?">
    <option value="Sharing">Sharing</option>
    <option value="Single Supplement">Single Supplement</option>
</select>
<div>
Cost:<br>
<button onclick="myFunction()">Get Cost</button>
<p id="cost"></p>
</div>
<script>
function myFunction() {
var date = document.getElementsByName("date");
var people = document.getElementsByName("people");
var month = date.substring(0, 2);
var year = date.substring(8, 10);
var time = month.concat(year);
if(people == "Sharing"){
if(time == "1015"){document.getElementById("cost").innerHTML = "18,450";}
if(time == "1115"){document.getElementById("cost").innerHTML = "19,000";}
if(time == "1215"){document.getElementById("cost").innerHTML = "19,000";}
if(time == "0116"){document.getElementById("cost").innerHTML = "19,350";}
if(time == "0216"){document.getElementById("cost").innerHTML = "19,350";}
if(time == "0316"){document.getElementById("cost").innerHTML = "19,350";}
if(time == "0416"){document.getElementById("cost").innerHTML = "18,800";}
}
if(people == "Single Supplement"){
if(time == "1015"){document.getElementById("cost").innerHTML = "11,150";}
if(time == "1115"){document.getElementById("cost").innerHTML = "11,600";}
if(time == "1215"){document.getElementById("cost").innerHTML = "11,600";}
if(time == "0116"){document.getElementById("cost").innerHTML = "11,780";}
if(time == "0216"){document.getElementById("cost").innerHTML = "11,780";}
if(time == "0316"){document.getElementById("cost").innerHTML = "11,780";}
if(time == "0416"){document.getElementById("cost").innerHTML = "11,200";}
}
}
</script>
```

So what is supposed to happen is var month takes the first 2 numbers of the date (the month) and var year takes the last 2 numbers (the year).
Then var time will put the month and year together so the 1st of January 2016 (01/01/2016) would become 0116.
The the if (people == "...") will get whether you chose sharing or single supplement, and then get the correct cost based on the date, and the people.
However, when I press the button to get the cost, nothing seems to happen.

I feel like it will be a blatantly obvious problem, but I just can't see it.

Comment: The `.getElementsByName()` function always returns a **list** of elements. You can't treat the list as if it were a single element; even if you could, you're comparing to plain strings, and that doesn't make sense either.

Comment: @j08691 Probably only used for the datepicker.

Comment: Yeah, jquery is used for the datepicker, I was just unsure if that would cause issues.
@Pointy what do you mean? Is there a way I can do something similar with what I have?

Comment: I mean that `.getElementsByName()` returns a **list** - a list of DOM elements, possibly empty if none have the requested name. You're taking the result of that call (`people`) and comparing it to plain strings. That will never work.

Comment: So my question then... Is there an alternative way to get the contents of the input and select field, and use it as a string?

Comment: @jordsta95 A possible solution to your question lies within my answer (using jQuery selectors, `$('#myElement').val()`)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Pointy has explanained to you, `.getElementsByName()` returns a list of DOM elements, you can read about it [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByName).

So, even when you have just one element that matchs that name, you need to select **that** element and not the list.

You can do it in this way:

```
var date = document.getElementsByName("date")[0];
```

And, actually, you don't want the element, but its value, so it becomes:

```
var date = document.getElementsByName("date")[0].value;
```

It would be cleaner to assign an *id* to the *input* elements to access them in this way:

```
var date = document.getElementsById("myDateInput").value;
```

Or, if you are using jQuery:

```
var date = $("#date").val();
```

I leave you a snippet:

```js
function myFunction() {
  var date = $("#date").val();
  var people = $("#people").val(); 
  var month = date.substring(0, 2);
  var year = date.substring(8, 10);
  var time = month.concat(year);

  if(people == "Sharing"){
    if(time == "1015"){$("#cost").html("18,450");}
    if(time == "1115"){$("#cost").html("19,000");}
    if(time == "1215"){$("#cost").html("19,000");}
    if(time == "0116"){$("#cost").html("19,350");}
    if(time == "0216"){$("#cost").html("19,350");}
    if(time == "0316"){$("#cost").html("19,350");}
    if(time == "0416"){$("#cost").html("18,800");}
  }
  if(people == "Single Supplement"){
    if(time == "1015"){$("#cost").html("11,150");}
    if(time == "1115"){$("#cost").html("11,600");}
    if(time == "1215"){$("#cost").html("11,600");}
    if(time == "0116"){$("#cost").html("11,780");}
    if(time == "0216"){$("#cost").html("11,780");}
    if(time == "0316"){$("#cost").html("11,780");}
    if(time == "0416"){$("#cost").html("11,200");}
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>
  <input id="date" type="text" id="datepicker" name="date" value="Choose when you want to go">
</p>
<select id="people" name="people" value="Are you sharing or single supplement?">
  <option value="Sharing">Sharing</option>
  <option value="Single Supplement">Single Supplement</option>
</select>
<div>
  Cost:
  <br>
  <button onclick="myFunction()">Get Cost</button>
  <p id="cost"></p>
</div>
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: ID's work too. I just didn't know if they were the same... as you can tell, I don't do much javascript :/

Comment: @jordsta95: The _id_ attribute suits you better as you are selecting an unique element. Hope you have it was useful for you :)

Answer (score 0):

### Solution

**JavaScript / jQuery**

```
function myFunction() {
    var date = $("#datepicker").val();
    var people = $('[name="people"]').eq(0).val();
    var month = date.substring(0, 2);
    var year = date.substring(8, 10);
    var time = month.concat(year);

    var costArray = {
        sharing: {
            1015: "18,450",
            1115: "19,000",
            1215: "19,000",
            0116: "19,350",
            0216: "19,350",
            0316: "19,350",
            0416: "18,800"
        },
        single: {
            1015: "11,150",
            1115: "11,600",
            1215: "11,600",
            0116: "11,780",
            0216: "11,780",
            0316: "11,780",
            0416: "11,200"
        }
    };

    if (people == "Sharing") {
        $("#cost").text(costArray.sharing[time]);
    } else {
        $("#cost").text(costArray.single[time]);
    }
}
```

[**JSFiddle (working demo)**](https://jsfiddle.net/mvefu1o3/3/)

---

### Explanation

Since jQuery is already loaded within your code, why not use it in this function?

I modified the way you grab your input values, using the `id` attribute when possible (I suggest you add an `id` to your `select` too, way easier to access it. You can [read more on jQuery and how to use its selectors here](https://learn.jquery.com/about-jquery/how-jquery-works/) (learn.jquery.com)

**Note:** The reason why you want to use `id` attributes is simple: this is a **unique** value identifying your element.

It means this is the only element wearing this `id` value (if your HTML structure is valid) and thus makes it really simple to access this element, since using the `name` or `class` attributes will return you an array of elements instead of the element itself.

I created an object (called it costArray, don't really know why) which contains two sub-objects: `sharing` and `single`. Both of then can be accessed this way: `costArray.sharing` (considered as object properties). You can [read more on objects here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects) (MDN).

I simplified all your conditional statements by storing the possible `time` values and their associated costs within those objects, so whenever you do `costArray.sharing[1115]` it will access the cost linked to that time value.

I access the element with the id "cost" this way using jQuery: `$('#cost')`. Then I simply change its content: `$('#cost').text("myText")`(replacing "myText" with the cost value associated to the time).

This made the code way easier to read, functionnal and way more efficient (it doesn't have to go through all `if` statements and simply accesses the value it needs).